# SpringBoot - Delete method giving this exception -"exception":"org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException"

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm new to Springboot and trying to learn how it works. I'm building a small application, in which the delete method for the API is giving me this error.

```
{
    "timestamp":1508894413495,
    "status":400,
    "error":"Bad Request",
    "exception":"org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException",
    "message":"JSON parse error: Can not deserialize instance of int out of START_OBJECT token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of int out of START_OBJECT token at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@5685db7d; line: 1, column: 1]",
    "path":"/shoppinglist"
}
```

**My Constructor:**

```
private String title; private int shoppingListId;

public int getShoppingListId() {
    return shoppingListId;
} 
public void setShoppingListId(int shoppingListId) {
    this.shoppingListId = shoppingListId;
}
```

**My Controller:**

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.DELETE, value="/shoppinglist")
public void deleteShoppingList(@RequestBody int shoppingListId) {
    this.service.deleteShoppingList(shoppingListId);
}
```

**My Service:**

```
private List<ShoppingList> shoppingLists;

public ShoppingListService() {
            this.shoppingLists = new ArrayList<ShoppingList>();
            this.shoppingLists.add(new ShoppingList(1, "HEB"));
            this.shoppingLists.add(new ShoppingList(2, "Walmart"));
            this.shoppingLists.add(new ShoppingList(3, "Market Basket"));
            this.shoppingLists.add(new ShoppingList(4, "Kroger"));
        }

public void deleteShoppingList(int shoppingListId) {
    ShoppingList shoppingList = getShoppingListById(shoppingListId);
    this.shoppingLists.remove(shoppingList);
}

public ShoppingList getShoppingListById(int shoppingListId) {
    return this.shoppingLists.stream().filter(x -> x.getShoppingListId() == shoppingListId).findFirst().get();
}
```

The add functionality and update are working fine, but not sure why the delete is failing.

Comment: Can you show your request data? It's a json conversion error

Comment: How is your front-end perform delete request?

Comment: I'm doing the request via rest client.

Method: Delete
Headers: application/json
URL: http://localhost:8080/shoppinglist
Request Body: {"shoppingListId": 4}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the issue in that code.

I was trying to delete the item by just passing in the shoppingListId.

Then I updated my service by passing in the entire ShoppingList object and accessed the id from that object.

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.DELETE, value="/shoppinglist")
    public void deleteShoppingList(@RequestBody ShoppingList shoppingList) {
        this.service.deleteShoppingList(shoppingList.getShoppingListId());
    }
```

It worked for me.

Thanks!